# javax.validation.NotBlank missing validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have requirement that in common api module(multi module project) I can't use any kind of hibernate's validation annotations, so I did use one from javax.validation which is acceptable.

Problem starts when I want to validate my domain objects(I use vaadin) that contains NotBlank annotation. I get the following exception

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'name'
```

Validation is invoked by call

```
Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validateValue(beanType, propertyName, value)
```

Same code works perfectly with hibernate's NotBlank

Also @Size @NotNull from javax works fine.

Is it possible to provide NotBlank validator implementation to DefaultValidatorFactory?

Am I missing some dependency?
(I have hibernate-validator already)

Does NotBlank from javax works the same as NotBlank from hibernate(I mean does it validate strings?)

How to solve this?

Comment: can you tell which version of hibernate-validator do you have ?

Comment: What type of object you are using  on  this  annotation ? Integer ? String ?

Comment: Its 5.3.6.final

Comment: Validated field looks like this  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 250)
  private String name;

Comment: Okay, are you using the  spring boot  starter-web ? if not are  you  including this  dependency ? <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: Yes, I use, that was the cause of the problem > some nested dependency that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in the version you are using then. You need to update to 6.0.x series. With the current latest been 6.0.9. Note that the groupId is changed to org.hibernate.validator.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

the `javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank`is part of [Bean Validation 2.0](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html) and validator for it is not present in 5.3 series.

Comment: In the parent module we have latest version of the hibernate-validator(properties). However in module I work with I also have vaadin dependency which have dependency to spring-boot-starter-web which have this older validator version. I thought I had the newest one. Glad that went quick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Validation-api 2.0.1 contains `javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank` which is replacement for Hibernate's NotBlank. To use it you need dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

then in code

```
@NotBlank 
private String possibleBlankString;
```

Answer (score 0):

as [baeldung.com say](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) Per the JSR 380 specification, the validation-api dependency contains the standard validation APIs:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.Final</version>
```

Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of the validation API.
To use it, we must add the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>6.0.2.Final</version>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
<version>6.0.2.Final</version></dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> If the changes don't take effect, then restart IntelliJ IDEA.