# JPA, Hibernate validators - NotBlank validator not applying on String

Tags: hibernate, validation, gradle

I'm trying validate bean through controller

Stack: Spring boot 1.5.4, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-jdbc, Hibernate Validation 5, DB2

```
HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for
```

I added dependency for validation-api-2.0.1, I am not able to include both validation-api-2.0.1 & hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.

I am using gradle.

Please let me know how I make force both of them to work

Comment: You say you cannot use hibernate validator 6. Any reason for that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017134/javax-validation-notblank-missing-validator clearly suggests it is required.

Comment: Mine is not maven. I figured out, in my build.gradle file one of the dependencies declared at bottom is pulling hiberanate validator 5 again - so I excluded from that dependency as well.